# Richfaces PanelMenuItem reevaluating disabled not working

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

if i disable a PanelMenuItem i recognized that Richfaces adds some kind of javascript after this element which causes the element to be disabled. If i modify this script and set the disabled attribute to false and execute this script with firebug i can use the PanelMenuItem again. If i click on the item, the action will be called which seems wrong. My understanding is that JSF will remember the state to avoid tampered request. I assume that the Richfaces script changes the element to disabled after JSF is finished. So JSF still thinks this element is not disabled. If this is true, this would be very dangerous. Maybe i'm completely wrong or missing something. Would be nice if somebody could give me feedback on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as a bug.
`org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PanelMenuItemRenderer#doDecode` does not check `disabled` attribute (how usually do other components before executing action).

Reported in RF jira: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-12813

You can add more details to the issue in jira.